# Unity mesh collider problem. Sphere falls through mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a sphere to drop on my mesh that I have procedurally generated. The sphere unfortunately falls through the mesh. This code procedurally generates mesh. Aside from this code I have a sphere in unity that has rigid body attached to it and sphere collider. Unfortunately the sphere falls through the mesh and I do not understand why. Please help.

```
   using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PGC_Mesh : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Mesh mesh;

        Vector3[] vertices;
        int[] triangles;

        public int xSize = 20;
        public int zSize = 20;

        public Material grassMat;


        void Start()
        {
            mesh = new Mesh();
            GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material = grassMat;
            MeshCollider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
            CreateShape();
            UpdateMesh();
        }


        void CreateShape()
        {
            vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];

            int i = 0;
            for (int z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
                {
                    float height = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * .5f, z * .5f) * 10f;
                    vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, height, z);
                    i++;
                }
            }

            int myVertices = 0;
            int myTriangles = 0;
            triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];

            for(int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
                {
                    triangles[myTriangles + 0] = myVertices + (0);
                    triangles[myTriangles + 1] = myVertices + (xSize + 1);
                    triangles[myTriangles + 2] = myVertices + (1);
                    triangles[myTriangles + 3] = myVertices + (1);
                    triangles[myTriangles + 4] = myVertices + (xSize + 1);
                    triangles[myTriangles + 5] = myVertices + (xSize + 2);

                    myVertices++;
                    myTriangles += 6;
                }
                myVertices++;
            }


        }

        void UpdateMesh()
        {
            mesh.Clear();

            mesh.vertices = vertices;
            mesh.triangles = triangles;

            mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        }

        private void OnDrawGizmos()
        {
            if (vertices == null)
                return;
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
            {
                Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], .1f);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do

```
MeshCollider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
```

so you add the `MeshCollider` but never assign the actual mesh to it so it doesn't know how it looks like.

You should do

```
var collider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
collider.convex = true;
CreateShape();
UpdateMesh();
collider.sharedMesh = mesh;
```

see [`MeshCollider.sharedMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MeshCollider-sharedMesh.html).

---

Also see [`MeshCollider.convex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MeshCollider-convex.html)

> Enable the checkbox to make the Mesh Collider collide with other Mesh Colliders.
>
> This means that if you have this set to true, your mesh collider wont have holes or entrances. Convex meshes can collide with other convex colliders and non-convex meshes. Thus convex mesh colliders are suitable on rigidibodies, if you really need more detailed colliders than what the primitive colliders provide you with.
>
> **Note**: A convex mesh is required by the physics engine to have a non-zero volume. Flat meshes such as quads or planes that are marked as convex will be modified by the physics engine to have a thickness (and therefore a volume) to satisfy this requirement. The thickness of the resulting mesh is proportional to its size and can be up to 0.05 of its longest dimension in the plane of the mesh.

and especially note

> **Convex Mesh Colliders are limited to 255 triangles.**

---

Finally you might also be interested in setting a certain [`MeshCollider.cookingOptions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MeshCollider-cookingOptions.html) before assigning the new `sharedMesh`.

Answer (score 0):

I have determined the reason of why the sphere falls through the mesh. It is because the collider was not set in the right place. It should be set in the update function, not the start function.

Answer (score -1):

Does the mesh have a collider on it? Make sure that both it and your sphere have one, otherwise they'll go through each other.

Also, Tyler Thompson has the right idea. You are only using the UpdateMesh() function once because you are only calling it at the start of the program, since you've put it in the Start() function. Moving it to the general Update() function lets the program call for it continuously.